# How to make xkvview record keyreader defined keys?

Tags: key-value, xkeyval

Since `keyreader` is based on `xkeyval` i wonder if it’s possible to make it wokr with `xkvview` which comes with `xkeyval`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xkvview}
\usepackage{keyreader}

\makeatletter

% recorded
\define@boolkey{LI@package}[li@]{savemode}[true]{}
% not recorded
\krddefinekeys{LI@all}[li@]{%
   cmd/testa/;
}


\begin{document}
\xkvview{}
\end{document}
```

The example shows that keys defined with the `xkeyval` way are recognized but not the ones defined via `keyreader`. I thought `keyreader` uses the `xkeyval` commands internally so I expect it to be also in the `\xkvview{}` list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*keyreader* works with *xkvview*. Load *keyreader* before *xkvview*. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{keyreader}
\usepackage{xkvview}
\makeatletter
\krddefinekeys{fama}{%
  ord/keya/default;
  cmd/keyb;
  choice/keyc/center/center.do=\def\x##1{#1xx##1},left,right;
  bool/keyd/true;
}
\krddefinekeys{famb}{%
  choice/planet/Earth/Earth.do=\def\x##1{#1##1},Mars,Jupiter;
  bool/space travel/true;
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
%\xkvview{family=fama,default=[none]}
\xkvview{family=fama}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have to investigate why `keyc` is shown twice in this table.

EDIT:

`keyc` is shown twice because of a bug in the package *xkvview*. I provide a patch below:

```
\def\XKV@d@fine@ch@icekey#1[#2]{%
  \let\d@fault\relax
  \XKVV@tabulate{#1}{choice}{#2}%
  \XKV@define@default{#1}{#2}%
  \XKV@d@fine@ch@ic@key{#1}%
}
\def\XKV@d@fine@ch@ic@key#1{%
  \ifx\d@fault\relax
    \let\d@fault\@undefined
  \else
    \XKVV@tabulate{#1}{choice}{[none]}%
  \fi
  \ifXKV@pl\XKV@afterelsefi
    \expandafter\XKV@d@f@ne@ch@ic@k@y
  \else\XKV@afterfi
    \expandafter\XKV@d@f@ne@ch@ic@key
  \fi
  \csname\XKV@header#1\endcsname
}
```

The patch should be inserted at the end of *xkvview* or after loading *xkvview*.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I didn’t thick about the loading order. Sometimes it’s a too simple solution … I assume that you’ll fix the bug in a future release, won’t you?

Comment: @Tobi: I am not the maintainer of *xkvview* package. I will inform the maintainer. I have always wanted to write the *keyreader-view* package, because I would like to improve *xkvview* in some ways.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I misread your answer and thought it was a `keyreader` bug O:-) Thanks for informing the maintainer :-)